# Is CPCFC a definition or theorem?

Tags: geometry

CPCFC stands for "corresponding parts of congruent figures are congruent."  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPCTC) calls this a theorem, but I thought this was just the definition of congruence of figures (meaning polygons or other shapes made out of line segments).

If this is not how congruence of two figures is defined, then how is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a theorem with a very, very simple proof, as follows.

Let $T_1,T_2$ be congruent triangles.

By definition of congruence, there exists an isometry $F$ of the Euclidean plane such that $F(T_1)=T_2$.

Let $P_1$ be a "part" of $T_1$ (a side, an angle, etc.) By definition the corresponding "part" of $T_2$ is $P_2 = F(P_1)$.

Since $F(P_1) = P_2$ it follows that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are congruent.